# Create a weekly timetable using matplotlib

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

Edit: I changed Data Type to Pandas DataFrame that looks like this     `(datetime.datetime,int)` in order to make the problem more simple.

Original Post:

I have a numpy array of data reports that looks like this `(datetime.datetime,int,int)` and I can't seem to plot it right. I need the X axes to be a 24 hours and this array

```
np.array([datetime.datetime.time(x) for x in DataArr])
```

the Y should be the days(monday,tuesday and so on) from the datetime
and the int should give me different colors for different events but I can't find an example
in matplotlib's web site.

An example of what I'm looking for:

[image]

Comment: What actual kind of plot are you trying to make?

Comment: activity document - see linked photo https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B1zMb6jCvqUmNFJfcmxzMlhqS0k/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: @omryjs I've added your picture inline, once you have enough reputation you'll be able to do this yourself.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you want something like this?

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.dates as mdates

# I'm using pandas here just to easily create a series of dates.
time = pd.date_range('01/01/2013', '05/20/2013', freq='2H')
z = np.random.random(time.size)

# There are other ways to do this, but we'll exploit how matplotlib internally
# handles dates. They're floats where a difference of 1.0 corresponds to 1 day.
# Therefore, modulo 1 results in the time of day. The +1000 yields a valid date.
t = mdates.date2num(time) % 1 + 1000

# Pandas makes getting the day of the week trivial...
day = time.dayofweek

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
scat = ax.scatter(t, day, c=z, s=100, edgecolor='none')
ax.xaxis_date()

ax.set(yticks=range(7),
       yticklabels=['Mon', 'Tues', 'Wed', 'Thurs', 'Fri', 'Sat', 'Sun'])

# Optional formatting tweaks
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(mdates.DateFormatter('%l%p'))
ax.margins(0.05)
fig.colorbar(scat)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: I'm trying to run your code but I get "AttributeError:'module' object has no attribute 'subplots'" Error. for the line "fig,ax=plt.subplots()

Comment: my matplotlib.__version__==
'1.2.1'

Comment: I've updated my libs but unfortunately I can't get a plot from the code you provided - I's basically what I'm looking for. check out the photo I linked above but I'm trying to get something like this

Comment: @omryjs how did you update matplotlib? if you did it by hand, did you remove the old version before installing the new?

Comment: @FrancescoMontesano I updated by using the .exe file from the matplotlib web site.

Comment: @omryjs - Sorry about that, I had a typo in the example.  However, the typo would have caused a different error.  You shouldn't be getting an error regarding `subplots` if you're using a version of matplotlib newer than 1.0.  (It was added in v1.0.  If you'd prefer, you can do `fig = plt.figure(); ax = plt.subplot(111)`.)

Comment: @omryjs Using matplotlib `1.2.1` I have no problem reproducing the plot in the answer here.

Comment: @omryjs - There's a difference between `subplot` and `subplots`.  `subplots` creates a new figure and an axes (or multiple axes).  `subplot` creates a single axes using the current figure (and doesn't return the figure object). If you're going to use `subplots`, then do `fig, ax = plt.subplots()`.

Comment: @omryjs - Also, if you're able to call `subplots`, the the problem isn't with your version of matplotlib.  Does the example code not run? If it doesn't, what error message do you get?

Comment: @Hooked mybe there is a problem in my interpreter - do you know how I can check this ?

Comment: @omryjs Without knowing what modules you have installed, or even what _OS_ you are using it's hard to diagnose it from here. If it's Windows (based off you calling it an `exe` file), trying completely reinstalling matplotlib or the package it came with (e.g. Enthought...).

Comment: @omryjs - Hooked is quite correct, but it will also help if you can give the exact error and traceback that you get.  Is it the exact same error that you mentioned in your first comment?  Or is there no error and does the plot just not show up?

Comment: @Hooked & JoeKington First of all thank you for your time and interest.   
my setup:Python 2.7.3 (default, Apr 10 2012, 23:31:26) [MSC v.1500 32 bit (Intel)] on win32
When I run the code I get a blank Figure & 
The Error message:
'' Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\lib\lib-tk\Tkinter.py", line 1410, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\backends\backend_tkagg.py", line 276, in resize
    self.show() '' & it goes on for more matplotlib error lines & ends in "ValueError: Invalid format string"

Comment: @JoeKington in what version of python are you working? I've done some googling and there might be a problem in the python interpreter in the new version